# PhoneGap - Open external application

Tags: javascript, android, ios, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I am developing a PhoneGap App, 
All what I need is to open an external application.

e.g. my app namespace is **com.demo.app1** and I need to open the **com.demo.app2** application, 
Is this feasible ?

- I am using PhoneGap 3.3
- I found that there is many versions of the WebIntent plugin
- An example may help :)

Thanks

Comment: for android you have the webintent plugin. for ios I have no idea.

Comment: how can I use it to open an app by package name ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I implemented my own plugin that offer the following:

- getUniqueDeviceId (return a unique device ID)
- openApp (open an installed app, and fallback to the store if available)
- openStore (open the store on a specific app)

http://ahmad-moussawi.github.io/pgutils/

Please feel free to contribute or suggest any other feature.

Comment: @jcesarmobile, what I have added, the iOS support, in addition to the openStore fallback.

Answer (score 7):

You can crea a plugin with this java code:

```
Intent LaunchIntent = this.cordova.getActivity().getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.demo.app2");
this.cordova.getActivity().startActivity(LaunchIntent);
```

or try any of this 2 plugins for launching apps

https://github.com/lampaa/org.apache.cordova.startapp

https://github.com/dmedvinsky/cordova-startapp

Comment: Many Thanks!, this https://github.com/lampaa/org.apache.cordova.startapp worked for me on PhoneGap 3.3

Answer (score 3):

Finally found my old code of when I was using webintent :

```
   CDV.WEBINTENT.launchActivity("com.demo.app1",
            function() {
                console.log("Activity started");
            },
            function() {
                console.log("Error starting activity");
            }
    );
```

There are two different gits for webintent referenced in phonegap build for phonegap 3.x, no idea what the differences are (and the first one is the one I was using) :

- https://github.com/InQBarna/WebIntent.git
- https://github.com/Tunts/WebIntent/
- https://github.com/acen99/WebIntent/

And an other usefull plugin is the webavailability plugin that lets you know if the other app is installed before you try to launch it : https://github.com/ohh2ahh/AppAvailability.git

I stopped using webintent because I needed to be able to switch to an app if it was already started and not relanch it.

EDIT:
oops again, launchactivity was a function I added to the plugin... will check later how I was doing before this.

Comment: thanks, but it seems this does not support phonegap 3.3

Comment: oops sorry a little to fast on pasting a link. I remember I've used a plugin before I had to build my own but can't remember the url I was using. This one seems to be compatible with 3.x : https://github.com/lampaa/org.apache.cordova.startapp

Answer (score 1):

In iOS to open any application you need to know which URLs schemes supported by this app.

For example,  you can open email-writer by url like "mailto:aaa@bbb.com". But the thing is in application you can declare your own scheme. For example in App1 you can [declare scheme](http://docs.build.phonegap.com/en_US/3.1.0/configuring_custom_urls.md.html#Custom%20URL%20Schemes) like "my-app1-scheme". And in your second app you will need to open URL "my-app1-scheme://" and your App1 will be opened.

And I just found this plugin that allows you to do this in simpler way: https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/LaunchMyApp-PhoneGap-Plugin