# Ionic - Launch apk in my app

Tags: cordova, xamarin, ionic-framework, xamarin.android

Do you know how I can launch external application in my application ?
For exemple, in my application I have a button "Launch calculator" and they open the calculator.apk (calculator.apk is not downloaded from the store)

If you have the answer for Xamarin I want too.

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PhoneGap - Open external application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22168015/phonegap-open-external-application)

Comment: Didn't see sry I try it !

Answer (score 1):

This is a native feature. Maybe this plugin help you.

https://github.com/lampaa/com.lampa.startapp

Answer (score 0):

#### `Xamarin.Android`

```
var intent = new Intent();
intent.SetClassName("com.android.calculator2", "com.android.calculator2.Calculator");
StartActivity(intent);
```

Note: This assumes that the default Android calculator is installed, some providers install their own *"wiz-bang feature loaded"* calculator instead of the default one from the ASOP.

Comment: Well I would like to launch my own calculator (downloaded from my application)

Comment: @maskedman Then you would have the package and the activity (class) that you need to open, so `SetClassName` takes two arguments: `string packageName`, `string className`

Comment: That is a Android specific method using an Intent to start an Activity (external app or not) within your app... You might want to look at `App Links`, there is a Nuget by Xamarin called `Rivets` that assists in cross-platform url linking: https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/cross-platform/app-links/  https://github.com/xamarin/Rivets